Elliptic Function as function of Lattice
I am talking in reference to the book Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms. I started reading the section 1.3 Modular Forms. First it says that an elliptic function can be viewed as a function of a lattice. I am not sure what is that supposed to mean. My interpretation is that, given an elliptic function $f(u)$ with periods in $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} i $, The same function is also an elliptic function $f(u)$ with periods in $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} (1+i) $ because
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}1 \\ 1 + i   \end{matrix} \right] =\left[ \begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1   \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix}1 \\  i   \end{matrix} \right] $$ is a unimodular transformation. So to emphasize the choice of a fixed lattice, I think they are considering an elliptic function as a function of a lattice. Is this correct?
On the next page, they have written that
Given an elliptic function $f(u, \omega_1, \omega_2)$ as a function of the variable $u$, and the lattice $\mathbb{Z} \omega_1 + \mathbb{Z} \omega_2$, we assume that $f(u)$ is homogenous in the variable $u$ or degree $k$, then we have
$$f(u, \omega_1, \omega_2)= f\Big(\frac{u}{\omega_2}, \frac{\omega_1}{\omega_2}\Big)$$
Where $f(u, z)$ is a function on $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{H}$. Given a matrix $$\gamma = \left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right)\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$$, Now as a function of $z$
we have
$$f(\gamma z) = (cz+ d)^{k} f(z)$$
I think I need to fix $v$ in this case, and vary $z$ only, so I wanted to prove that
$$f\Big(v, \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\Big) = (cz+ d)^{k} f(v, z)$$
However when I use homogenity, I am unable to proceed since there is an effect on the variable $v$ as well. My first step was
$$f\Big(v, \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\Big)=(cz+d)^{-k}f(v(cz+d), az+b)$$
But I have not been able to proceed from here.
